# Erro ao modificar coluna de uma View com cálculo

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

Preciso inserir uma coluna de cálculo nessa view abaixo, mas aparece a mensagem

> Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ConsolidadoEstudoBaseSifix, Line
>   4 [Batch Start Line 9] All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT
>   or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their
>   target lists.

Sei que o erro está no `UNION ALL`, mas no caso não queria inserir mais colunas no "percentual."

Como posso resolver essa questão?

Segue código:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER VIEW [dbo].[ConsolidadoBaseSifis] AS

with contabilidade as ( 

SELECT iUnidade,
COUNT(iUnidade) AS iQuantidade,
COUNT(vSimNao)  AS iSimNaoRespondido,
COUNT(vResp)  AS iJustificRespondidas
FROM  [dbo].[BaseSifis]
GROUP BY iUnidade
),

percentual as(

SELECT
(((iSimNaoRespondido+iJustificRespondidas)/iUnidade)*100) as iPorc
from contabilidade

)

select * FROM contabilidade 

Union ALL

select * FROM percentual
```

Em resumo, ela está assim:

[image: atual]

E gostaria que ficasse assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

O script original é este:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ConsolidadoBaseSifis] AS
    with contabilidade as ( 

    SELECT iUnidade,
    COUNT(iUnidade) AS iQuantidade,
    COUNT(vSimNao)  AS iSimNaoRespondido,
    COUNT(vResp)  AS iJustificRespondidas
    FROM  [dbo].[EstudoBaseSifis]
    GROUP BY iUnidade
    )

    select * FROM contabilidade 
GO
```

Comment: No `UNION` tem de haver correspondência entre as colunas de cada tabela. O que pretende juntar nas duas tabelas? A coluna `iPorc` corresponde a que coluna da tabela `contabilidade`?

Comment: No caso, eu quero criar uma coluna iPorc que é = (((iSimNaoRespondido+iJustificRespondidas)/iUnidade)*100) ... tentei criar esta iPorc dentro de contabilidad, porém ele faz referência a colunas que estão sendo criadas por ela...

Comment: Edite a sua questão e coloque lá o código, senão é difícil de perceber.

Comment: Ok, inseri duas imagens para ficar mais fácil visualizar

Comment: E coloquei o script original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente dessa forma:

```
ALTER VIEW ConsolidadoBaseSifis
AS
    WITH contabilidade  AS 
    ( 
        SELECT      iUnidade
                ,   COUNT(iUnidade) AS iQuantidade
                ,   COUNT(vSimNao)  AS iSimNaoRespondido
                ,   COUNT(vResp)    AS iJustificRespondidas
        FROM        BaseSifis
        GROUP BY    iUnidade
    ),  percentual      AS
    (
        SELECT  iUnidade
            ,   iQuantidade
            ,   iSimNaoRespondido
            ,   iJustificRespondidas
            ,   (((iSimNaoRespondido + iJustificRespondidas) / iUnidade) * 100) AS iPorc
        FROM    contabilidade
    )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    percentual
GO
```

Se não quiser mesmo colocar mais colunas, para além do `iPorc` e claro, a `iUnidade` (caso contrário não conseguirá ligar as duas tabelas), poderá fazer assim:

```
ALTER VIEW ConsolidadoBaseSifis
AS
    WITH contabilidade  AS 
    ( 
        SELECT      iUnidade
                ,   COUNT(iUnidade) AS iQuantidade
                ,   COUNT(vSimNao)  AS iSimNaoRespondido
                ,   COUNT(vResp)    AS iJustificRespondidas
        FROM        BaseSifis
        GROUP BY    iUnidade
    ),  percentual      AS
    (
        SELECT  iUnidade
            ,   (((iSimNaoRespondido + iJustificRespondidas) / iUnidade) * 100) AS iPorc
        FROM    contabilidade
    )
    SELECT      iUnidade
            ,   iQuantidade             = SUM(iQuantidade)
            ,   iSimNaoRespondido       = SUM(iSimNaoRespondido)
            ,   iJustificRespondidas    = SUM(iJustificRespondidas)
            ,   iPorc                   = SUM(iPorc)
    FROM        (
                    SELECT  iUnidade
                        ,   iQuantidade
                        ,   iSimNaoRespondido
                        ,   iJustificRespondidas
                        ,   iPorc = 0
                    FROM    contabilidade 
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT  iUnidade
                        ,   iQuantidade             = 0
                        ,   iSimNaoRespondido       = 0
                        ,   iJustificRespondidas    = 0
                        ,   iPorc
                    FROM    percentual 
                ) X
    GROUP BY    iUnidade
GO
```

Mas parece-me algo demasiado trabalhoso e pouco *performante* quando o que queremos é, basicamente, o resultado da tabela `percentual`.

Comment: Excelente!! 
A primeira opção deu certo!! Obrigado!!

Comment: De nada! Marque a resposta como válida e dê um UP :)